# Line Character / Default Line Endings in Coda 2

Tags: character-encoding, coda, line-endings

I am having some issues with Coda 2.  I work in a hybrid Windows/Mac environment and I am on a mac running Coda 2 to do my development work.  After hitting **Command ,** I set my default File Encoding to Unicode (UTF-8) and my Default Line Endings to Windows.  Yet if you open one of my files in Notepad++ on a Windows environment it says that the file was saved with UNIX end-of-line characters.

[image: Editor Settings]

Any ideas on how to get around this?  I have done some research online and everybody seems to think that once these options are set that I should be fine, but it's not...I am running Coda 2.0.9

[image: Coda Version 2.0.9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the only time this happen is when I send an HTML file via email.  If I sent that file as a zip file it is fine, or if I load it to an FTP location it's fine.  Not coda's fault at all.